# RegEx in PHP with preg_match

Tags: php, regex

I have a reg exp which is supposed to check if there are any illegal characters in a name. THe allowed characters are 0-9, a-z, A-Z, middlescore(-) and underscore( _ ).

This is the function

```
function validate_playername($playername){
    if (preg_match('/^[0-9A-Z-_]$/i',$playername)) {
        return true;
    } else{
        return false;
    }

}
```

the function is called like this

```
if (validate_playername($addplayer)) {
    echo "valid player Name";
} else {
    echo "Invalid Player Name";
}
```

However when I enter a correct name like velocity28 it returns as an Invalid player name. Is my reg exp wrong?

Comment: Try escaping the last hyphen with a slash.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`/^[0-9A-Z-_]$/i` matches only one character.

Append `+` to match multiple characters:

```
'/^[-0-9A-Z_]+$/i'
```

- moved `-` to the beginning.

**UPDATE**

As Enissay commented, the regular expression can be simplified using `\w`:

```
'/^[-\w]+$/'
```

Comment: You can also add `{2,6}` instead of `+` to require a name with min 2 chars and max 6 chars for example

Comment: @RonaldFernandes, you may need to add `a-z` if you want it to match lower case letters also, as you requested `THe allowed characters are 0-9, a-z, A-Z, middlescore(-) and underscore( _ )`... Then falsetru's expression can be simplified to `/^[-\w]+$/i` since the `\w` matches any word character (letter, number, underscore)

Comment: @Enissay, `i` flag used, so no need to add `a-z`. The idea of Simplifying by using `\w` is good.

Comment: @Enissay, I mentioned the simplified version. Thank you.

Comment: @falsetru, ow, my bad, I didnt notice the case insensitive flag xD... :)

Comment: Yes using the /w makes it much more simple. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To use a literal minus sign in a character class, it must be escaped with a backslash:

```
   function validate_playername($playername){
    if (preg_match('/^[0-9A-Z\-_]$/i',$playername)) {
        return true;
    } else{
        return false;
    }

   }
```

See http://php.net/manual/de/regexp.reference.character-classes.php for further information.

You could also move the minus sign to a position where it can't be part of character range definition, e.g. make it the first character in the character class.